# simple login form with mysql databse whose name of the user will appear on another

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm trying to create a simple login form with mysql database that I will use for my actual program. My only problem is that every time I login the 1st account that i created a few days back it's name appears on the label in the second form but when I login the 2nd account i just created very recently,it logs in but it's name doesn't appear on the label but the name of the 1st account always appears...

the codes I'm using for the name to appear on the label in the second form:

```
string lsq = "select * from admintable";
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(mysqlAddress2);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(lsq,cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            label2.Text = string.Empty;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                label2.Text += dr.GetString("AdminName"); 
                break;
        }
```

I'm not sure if those codes is the right one but those codes works but the result that I want is very different. The result that I want is that every time a user would login its name will appear on the label much like on most social media sites....

Comment: Could you give us the structure of `admintable`? You should select the latest `AdminName`, like `select AdminName from admintable order by LastLogin desc limit 1`

Comment: where there ya go. Select * with no `where` and a `break` ,,, bingo, you get clustered index #1 entry

Comment: @Alex it is `mysql`. no `top`

Comment: @Drew thanks for point it out, I have edit it and also apply the `desc` (forgot ...)

Comment: @Alex how about you just answer the question if you get my drift from my comment about the `break` and we wrap this easy one up

Comment: so Jan it is your turn to talk. What do you want to do with the login name from a textbox and how does that relate to anything in the code you showed? Otherwise we just close the question as Unclear

Comment: @Drew are you referring to the username login? The only thing that it relates to the code is the dr.getstring(); because it gets the string name from the database and like i said I want the user's name to appear on the label everytime it logs in much like in every social media sites, but what i didn't included on my question is that when a second user is about to log-in its name would appear on the very same label.... sorry! my bad though..... and if my question and comment is too vague, feel free to close it...

Answer (score 0):

You should use **where** clause and pass the parameter for getting the name of that UserName.

Comment: It would be a good answer if you showed a block of code that demonstrates binding a variable, and some `using` code for safe disposal of resources. Right now this is a comment from you.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that you have a `datetime` field to store when the user login, which named `LastLogin`

```
// select last login name based on [LastLogin]
string lsq = "select AdminName from admintable order by LastLogin desc limit 1";
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(mysqlAddress2);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(lsq,cnn);
cnn.Open();

var lastAdminName = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (lastAdminName != null)           // to handle no record return from DB
    label2.Text = lastAdminName.ToString();
```